# How to give a random direction to a square in Tkinter, Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My Tkinter animation (just a square moving) doesn't have an orderly movement. It just does a "random walk" which is not my intention. I'm trying to set a random direction first, but I'd like the square to follow through with that random direction until it hits the "wall". But like I said, it just moves randomly.

```
def animate():

    dx = random.randint(-5, 5)
    dy = random.randint(-5, 5)

    if(check_crash() == 1):
        print("crash on X axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
        dx = dx * (-1)

    elif(check_crash() == 2):
        print("crash on Y axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
        dy = dy * (-1)

    canvas.move(square, dx, dy)
    root.after(50, animate)
```

I know every time animate() gets called I'm generating new random values and that's why my animation isn't working like I want. But if I take dx/dy out of the animate() then I'd have to do something like animate(dx,dy), and I've tried that and got an error.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `dx`, `dy` outside animation and use `global` inside animation to change use this external variables instead of local one. It will keep position when you run animation again with `after()`

```
def animate():
    global dx
    global dy

    if(check_crash() == 1):
        print("crash on X axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
        dx = dx * (-1)

    elif(check_crash() == 2):
        print("crash on Y axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
        dy = dy * (-1)

    canvas.move(square, dx, dy)
    root.after(50, animate)

dx = random.randint(-5, 5)
dy = random.randint(-5, 5)
animate()
```

Instead of `global` you can send values as function's arguments but you have to do the same in `after()`

```
def animate(dx, dy):

    if(check_crash() == 1):
        print("crash on X axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
        dx = dx * (-1)

    elif(check_crash() == 2):
        print("crash on Y axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
        dy = dy * (-1)

    canvas.move(square, dx, dy)
    root.after(50, animate, (dx, dy))

dx = random.randint(-5, 5)
dy = random.randint(-5, 5)
animate(dx, dy)
```

I'm not sure if `after()` need it as tuple or not `after(50, animate, dx, dy)`

Comment: Awesome! it worked! I think I might use the first method, but you also fixed the error I was getting when defining random values outside of animate() Thanks dude!

Comment: people say that using `global` is not good idea because it makes code less readable but sometimes it is easier or the only solution.

Comment: yea I know what you mean..but yeah `global` is perfect for this situation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to make the square constantly 'walk' in the same direction, once every 50 seconds, for example.

You can do this by defining the random direction and then starting the loop.

The loop runs while the variable 'flag' = True

The loop makes the square 'walk' in the randomly generated direction.

The direction is not re-generated each time the square 'walks'. This is because the randomly generated direction is generated before the loop is run, so when the loop loops, the direction is not randomly generated again.

I have made changes (as you can see below) to your code so that it no longer uses recursion but iteration so that the code that randomly generates the direction is only run once.

You will need to add a condition to the while loop that sets 'flag' to False if you want the loop to end. Currently, the loop continues forever.

Note: I put code of yours that I removed into comments, e.g. #root.after(50, animate)

```
def animate():

    leftorright = random.randint(1,2) #1 = LEFT, 2 = RIGHT
    if leftorright = 1: #(LEFTWARDS)
        dx = random.randint(-5, -1) #A random leftwards movement of 1-5 pixels
    elif leftorright = 2: #(RIGHTWARDS)
        dx = random.randint(1, 5) #A random rightwards movement of 1-5 pixels

    upordown = random.randint(1,2) #1 = UP, 2 = DOWN
    if upordown = 1: #(UPWARDS)
        dy = random.randint(-5, -1) #A random upwards movement of 1-5 pixels
    elif leftorright = 2: #(DOWNWARDS)
        dy = random.randint(1, 5) #A random downwards movement of 1-5 pixels

    flag = True

    while flag = True:

        if(check_crash() == 1):
            print("crash on X axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
            dx = dx * (-1)

        elif(check_crash() == 2):
            print("crash on Y axis: ", canvas.coords(square))
            dy = dy * (-1)

        canvas.move(square, dx, dy)

        time.sleep(50)

    #root.after(50, animate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, mate! It's still doing a "random walk" though..I think I need a way to generate random values and then stop the animate() function from generating new values so the square keeps moving in the first random direction.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I will change my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it now solves your problem!